# Pass value to controller action with check_box in Rails5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, ruby-on-rails-5

Currently, a button is passing the `id` of an object to a controller action when clicked.

Now I want to create a checkbox with the same functionality.

**Current button code:**

```
<%= link_to "Display", note_display_path(:id => n.id), method: :post, class: 'btn btn-default' %>
```

**Attempted checkbox code:**

```
<%= check_box n, note_display_path(:id => n.id), method: :post %>
```

This is what I'm trying now, but I'm not seeing any activity in the terminal when clicked.

Its on an `index` template so there are lots of object being iterated through and displayed, `@notes.each do |n|`.

But this does not need to be asynchronous; its ok if the page refreshes.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to partially solve by setting up a `form_for` in the `<% @notes.each do |n| %>` loop.

And then hiding the submit button.

```
<%= form_for n, :url => { controller: :notes, action: :post_it, :id => n.id } do |f| %>
  <td> <%= f.check_box :posted %> </td>
  <td> <%= f.submit '', style: 'display:none' %> </td>
<% end %>
```

An improved version I haven't figured out yet might submit when clicking on the `check_box`, without needing to press enter.

Answer (score 0):

I would try "onclick" with some javascript, possibly like this:

```
<%= check_box_tag(:name, :value, false, {onclick: "sendNotes(id='#{n.id}')"%>

<script>
    function sendNotes(id) {
        window.location.search += "note_id="+id;
    }

</script>
```

Then you can do something with `params[:note_id]` in your controller